# Exact field search in the Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I'm trying to configure the Django admin bindings for a specific model so that I can quickly filter by the exact value of a specific field. I know I can manually tamper with the GET parameters to do this:

```
?fieldname__exact=foobar
```

What I can't seem to do, is get the sidebar to display a small form where I can enter this value. I know I can add `fieldname` to `list_filter`, but that doesn't scale well beyond tens of unique values. I looked into django-advanced-filters for a bit, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Django 1.11.

How can I implement exact search for a specific field in the Django admin?

Answer (score 34):

a little late but i hope it still helps someone

the possible configurations for the searchfield are listed at  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter.

> ```
> '^' Starts-with search.
> '=' Exact matches. (case-insensitive)
> '@' Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's MySQL backend.)
> '$' Regex search. (Only with Django Rest Framework)
> ```

In your case, just add

```
search_fields = ['=fieldname', 'otherfieldname']
```

to your admin.

Update:
Since Django 2.1 it is also possible to add lookups to the search fields (e.g. 'fieldname__exact'). You can find infos in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields), as well as the possible [Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

Comment: Interesting feature, but unfortunately that doesn't allow for a separate search boxes specifically for one field, does it?

Comment: No it is the same searchfield for every field. I'm afraid a separate field is only possible with HTML/Javascript.

Comment: Also documented in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)

Comment: The regex search is not available in django admin, only in DRF. Also, the exact match is case insensitive.

Comment: @Pieter did you find any solution for separate search boxes specifically for one field?

Comment: From what I recall we ended up manually creating separate filters for each field I wanted a separate search box for. More of a last resort than a real solution, but it was good to have a workaround.